# android service by mean share by all activities

Tags: android, service

Android: i want to create service by extending a Service class which i start when application get started and all activities can share its state and when i want stop it from other activity and when i want start it again from any activity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own `MyApplication` class extending `Application` class, put it in `AndroidManifest.xml` as

```
<application ... android:name=".MyApplication"> ... </application>
```

and start your service and bind to it in `MyApplication.onCreate()` method.

You can access the binder from any `Activity` class:

```
Application app = getApplication();
MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication) app;
myApp.getServiceBinder() // need to implement this method first
```